# Java character codes

Tags: java, string, character-codes

I'm looking for terminator characters in Strings using indexOf.

```
// character codes to look for
int[] defseps = new int[] {10, 13, 34, 36, 38, 39,41, 44, 59, 63, 93, 125};
int t = 999999999;  // big number,  We want first terminator 
int tempt = 0;

// loop through possible terminators
for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {
    tempt=str.indexOf(defseps[x]); // Get index of terminator
    if (defsepactivated[x] && tempt!=-1) {  // If active terminator found
        System.out.println("defsep used=" + defseps[x]);
        if (tempt < t) t = tempt; // Use this terminator if before previous found  
    }
}
```

This code finds terminators like & (38) and ] (93) but not double quote (34).

For example if str is :  **=THINGTHUNG";copyright &copy** it finds the semi colon and & but not the double quote.

Much appreciate why that would be the case before I try other codings.

Comment: You can also loop through the String usign `toCharArray()`

Comment: It does find the double quotes. Did you step through the code with a debugger and see what the `tempt` value is when `x == 2`?

Comment: http://ideone.com/VWs6rl < "defsep used=34", check `defsepactivated[2]`, could be `false` P.s. you could use `char[] defseps = "]>\";%&".toCharArray();` if you want a simpler to read definition of your terminator characters

Comment: forgivenson be assured it wasn't lack of effort (2 days of sweat), just lack of brain and experience.  But without your confirmation I wouldn't have got there.

Comment: Many tx guys.  zapl I'll try that more readable but any thoughts on return and carriage line feed in the char array?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the index of the *first* occurrence of any one of your "terminator" characters in a string, use a character class regex of your characters:

```
if (!str.matches(".*[\n\r\"#&'),;?\\]}].*")) {
    // handle not found
} else {
    int t = str.split("[\n\r\"#&'),;?\\]}]")[0].length - 1;
}
```

FYI, most characters lose their special regex meaning when in a character class and don't need escaping, but of course `]` (which closes the character class) must be escaped.

Comment: Tx Bohemian.  Yes first one.  I'll have a look and see if I can form that regex as a string as sadly the terminators are not consistent so need to be selected from an options array.  But no matter what learning a lot.  Cheers

Comment: If you don't know until runtime what the characters will be, you can safely form a regex using literal delimiters, but the code to do that would be more than your loop using indexOf(), which should work OK.